# List roles in specific project in Google Cloud Platform using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-resource-manager

I am trying to learn the python SDK to help me to manage my Google Cloud Platform resources.  Can someone help me to understand.  I got the following code snippet from the Google API.
This code works alone. Let's say if I want to list all of the roles in my organization, or list a role of a particular project, where do I do it and how?

Thank you very much in advance.

```py
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

request = service.roles().list()
while True:
    response = request.execute()

    for role in response.get('roles', []):
        # TODO: Change code below to process each `role` resource:
        pprint(role)

    request = service.roles().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
    if request is None:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get IAM roles by using the "resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy for a project [1]. If this is what you are looking for, then you can use the following python library [2].

Here is a samp snippit that you can use that will return the IAM roles and the users assigned to them:

```
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    service = build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1')

    project_id = '[project_ID]'
    policy_request = service.projects().getIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body={})
    policy_response = policy_request.execute()

members = set()
for binding in policy_response['bindings']:
members |= set(binding['members'])

print('\n'.join(sorted(members)))
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/project/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy

[2] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/cloudresourcemanager/v1